# Using set_callback for after_commit on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

Rails 4.2.6:

I have an `after_commit` which is defined to only be executed on create by passing `on: :create` option.

In tests, I'm using `skip_callback` and `set_callback` to bypass this execution. However, I'm having issues to use `set_callback` properly back again as I can't figure out how to provide the `on: :create` option back.

I've been reading docs but no luck!

### Callback definition

`after_commit  :create_report, on: :create`

### Skip and Set statements

`Order.skip_callback(:commit, :after, :create_report)`

`Order.set_callback(:commit, :after, :create_report)`

Comment: What is the rails version ?

Comment: Hi Ashik! 4.2.6!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well. I was able to workaround by monkey patching the original class. In your case, it should probably work to do this:

### Short answer:

```rb
# disable your callbacks
Order.skip_callback(:commit, :after, :create_report)

# do whatever you need to do...

# Restore callbacks with monkey patch
class Order ; after_commit  :create_report, on: :create ; end
```

---

### Longer answer:

Read on for more detail below:

I was able to figure this out by looking at the `__callbacks`:

When it's originally defined, it looks like this:

```rb
:commit=>
  #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain:0x00007fbd0aceaf80
   @callbacks=
    #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackSequence:0x00007fbd4a2f18b8
     @after=
      [#<Proc:0x00007fbd4a2f0df0@/Users/ryanjodonnell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:256>],
     @before=[],
     @call_template=nil,
     @nested=nil,
     @user_conditions=nil>,
   @chain=
    [#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x00007fbd0aceb200
      @chain_config=
       {:scope=>[:kind, :name],
        :terminator=>
         #<Proc:0x00007fbd480e0670@/Users/ryanjodonnell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:603>},
      @filter=:create_report,
      @if=
       [#<Proc:0x00007fbd0aceb5c0@/Users/ryanjodonnell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:288 (lambda)>],
      @key=:create_report,
      @kind=:after,
      @name=:commit,
      @unless=[]>],
```

After you disable the callbacks with `Order.skip_callback(:commit, :after, :create_report)`, notice that your callback is now missing as expected:

```rb
 :commit=>
  #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain:0x00007fbd0b672ad0
   @callbacks=nil,
   @chain=[],
   @config=
    {:scope=>[:kind, :name],
     :terminator=>
      #<Proc:0x00007fbd480e0670@/Users/ryanjodonnell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:603>},
   @mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x00007fbd0b672a80>,
   @name=:commit>,
```

Now, re-create the callback with `Order.set_callback(:commit, :after, :create_report)`, you will notice that callback is restored, but missing the `@if=[#Proc]`

```rb
 :commit=>
  #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain:0x00007fbd0ae90790
   @callbacks=nil,
   @chain=
    [#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x00007fbd0ae90998
      @chain_config=
       {:scope=>[:kind, :name],
        :terminator=>
         #<Proc:0x00007fbd480e0670@/Users/ryanjodonnell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:603>},
      @filter=:create_report,
      @if=[],
      @key=:create_report,
      @kind=:after,
      @name=:commit,
      @unless=[]>],
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and details! A practical workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [after_commit](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit) documentation:

> Note that transactional fixtures do not play well with this feature. Please use the [test_after_commit](https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit) gem to have these hooks fired in tests.

Comment: Correct, `after_commit` transaction callbacks will not be executed if this gem is not added. However, I don't have issues with executing after commit callbacks this. I have issues for specific indirect tests which I want to avoid using the callback by `skip` and then `set` to restore actual settings. I'm able to `skip` but not `set`.